# Mirroring sql server , how to change the port?

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, mirroring

I have two servers on the same cluster, in fact my goal is to set up "high availability", but the databases that I have integrated are not synchronized, so I think it is " mirroring "that I created but the port on which the two servers is not the same, I have a 1433 on the other and a 5022 on the other. what should i do ?

Comment: 1433 is the default port used by SQL Server's client connection TCP endpoint, and 5022 is the default port used by SQL Server's mirroring/Always On endpoint. Can you provide more information about how you configured mirroring, what version you're running and what your actual problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the port when you set it up

```
ALTER DATABASE <DBNAME> SET PARTNER = 'TCP://<ServerName>.<Domain>.com:5022'
```